# Making a simple graphical OS

Tags: operating-systems

I want to make my own OS.

Now ***DON'T WORRY***, yes I know it takes time, you don't have to tell me! Plus, this isn't a huge, bleeding-edge, Windows-devastating OS idea, read on.

The idea is a very simple OS, something maybe for a game console, with simple UI. Here's a quick sketch I made, using games as examples (1920x1200):

[image]
DON'T TAKE THE PICTURE LITERALLY; I know it takes time. Just having the UI working is already enough, I can work up from that.

The reason I told you that much is so you can have a notion of the complexity of the OS.

Now to the question, how do I make an OS *easily*? I don't want to have to make a kernel. I just want to make the UI and add features right away. Is there any ready barebones OS to work up from or anything like that?

Yes, I'm a programmer, yes, I know ARM ASM, yes, I know C.

BTW, I haven't bought a Pi yet, so instead I'm using QEMU. Are there any big differences in relation to making software?

Comment: have you considered simply making it a program that goes overtop of a current distribution similar to how kodi and emulation station do it?

Comment: I never saw those (at least the code), can you give me a short description?

Comment: that are simply programs written in c that are packaged with the os, commonly  Raspbian because it is the most well maintained, and have the os call there program on boot. It isn't exactly an os but it is certainly much easier than to write an os, and also does to the end user feel like one, as you may even create your own iso

Comment: not a problem, if this is what you wanted, can i write up an answer to get them 15 points

Comment: There is a lot of low level stuff you need to do before you can even worry about UI. A kernel (of some sort) is pretty much required. It would be like saying you want to start writing Windows programs but don't want to write the OS behind it. I'd just build a full screen GUI app that sits on top of an existing windowing system. Not to mention you'd need a specific OS to play the games you are describing...

Comment: It's not exactly what I asked for, but it solves the problem already. Go ahead, write an answer

Comment: @RonBeyer I just wanted a base to make my own OS, kinda like Android, Debian, Ubuntu etc. use Linux (though I don't know how it works, that may be off).

Comment: @MohammadAli notify

Comment: @jv110 I've posted my answer sorry for the delay

Comment: SDL was designed for people like you. LXDE uses it for it's GUI so it is already there. I have a mp3 player that is ported to the SDL game designer library.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is unlikely that you will be able to create an os, and also that people on this site will be able to help you create an os. As there probably aren't to many tutorials of that online, and a lot of the gpu is held in secrecy so your own os will never be able to use hardware acceleration which is a big part in what lets popular pi uses operate smoothly along with many other optimizations. My personal recommendation to you is to create a gui in your favourite programming language and have it run whenever your pi boots similar to what projects such as kodi, and emulation station are doing, as this will allow you to spend more time on your program and less on the underlying os. Furthermore you are able to package your program into any pi os and create your own iso which gives the feeling to the end user that is pretty much the same to what they would be experiencing if you had created the os. best of luck with you piventures and feel free to open up new questions if you would like to inquire about the creation of a gui or on how to create your own linux distribution image(iso)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Mohammad said, but what you CAN do is start clean with Openbox or a different window manager like ICEWM or Fluxbox and basicly start messing around with different things, I did it and ended up with a custom LXDE OS made with Ubuntu :)